# unset() converts array into object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array from which I want to unset the first item, but when I do so, and I send the info as JSON, the result is read as an object.

The PHP array looks like this:

```
$myArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

and when I send this as JSON with `json_encode($myArray)` it is as I expect:

```
["one","two","three","four"]
```

But then when I first unset:

```
unset($myArray[0]);
```

...the JSON I get from `json_encode($myArray)` reads:

```
{"1":"one","2":"two"}
```

What makes it so, and how do I prevent it from showing up in object-notation?

From what I'm seeing, in PHP, the remaining array behaves like an array, and I can use array functions, such as `array_search`, `array_intersect`, etc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In JSON, arrays always start at index 0. So if in PHP you remove element 0, the array starts at 1. But this cannot be represented in array notation in JSON. So it is represented as an object, which supports key/value pairs.

To make JSON represent the data as an array, you must ensure that the array starts at index 0 and has no gaps.

To make that happen, don't use *unset*, but instead use [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
array_splice($myArray, 0, 1);
```

That way your array will shift, ensuring the first element will be at index 0.

If it is always the first element you want to remove, then you can use the shorter [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php):

```
array_shift($myArray);
```

If you don't want to mutate the original array, or potentially have several gaps, then `array_values` is the way to go, which returns a new array without gaps:

```
array_values($myArray);
```

Answer (score 19):

I am not so sure why it converts to an `object` instead of an `array`. That's surely because there no index `0` (indeed).

To prevent that, use `array_values` that reconstructs the indexes of the array:

```
unset($myArray[0]);
$myArray = array_values($myArray);
```

Comment: I went with the other solution, but +1 for the alternative and for function info.

Comment: I got an error that array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given.